# HTML5 - Audio tag for some reason does not work

Tags: html, audio, tags

I have made a Html5 page while learning tutorials and for some reason the  tag works for him but not for me.
I tried it in Opera and Firefox but in both nothing gets displayed. Just a plain empty webpage with my title.

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8"/>
        <title>DogePage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio control >
            <source src="music1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
            If you can see this update your browser
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it should be  `<audio controls>`

Comment: Thank you everyone I just marked the Ozgur Bar's answer because he made it the most tidy post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is not valid. `<audio>` tag does not have an attribute named `control`, it should be `controls`.

You need to change the markup like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8"/>
        <title>DogePage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio controls> <!-- not *control* -->
            <source src="music1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
            If you can see this update your browser
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

its controls not control
here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="abc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Everything is good in your code just missing "s" in control it should be controls

Like This:

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8"/>
        <title>DogePage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="music1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
            If you can see this update your browser
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```